# What happens if a user loses privileges?

Tags: discussion, privileges

What happens if a user loses the privilege to carry out an action? Does it stay done? For instance if a user with over 3000 reputation votes to close a question and then falls below 3000 does the question stay closed?

Comment: The user can even be deleted, and the closed vote will stay. There are many such examples around.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the question stays closed, but that user can't cast another close vote elsewhere or cast a reopen vote on that same question.

Basically, existing actions stay. New actions are subject to passing the privilege check at the time of performing the action.